# Does +percent damage-type increase a percentage of your weapon-damage, or only damage of that type?

Tags: diablo-iii

For example, the item [Tal Rasha's Adjudication](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-adjudication) randomly has one of the following stats:

> - Adds 5-6% to Arcane Damage
> - Adds 5-6% to Poison Damage
> - Adds 5-6% to Lightning Damage
> - Adds 5-6% to Holy Damage
> - Adds 5-6% to Cold Damage
> - Adds 5-6% to Fire Damage

In the case of, say, poison:  does the item give me +6% of my weapon damage (or total damage) as poison?  Or does it only add +6% to my current poison damage *(meaning if I have no poison damage, it does nothing)*?

If it's the latter-case, does `+20 poison damage` on my weapon affect this?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92331/how-is-x-dmg-to-elemental-skills-being-calculated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the test done in this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5762727556), "Adds X% to [Element] Damage" actually means "Adds X% to Total Damage as [Element]".

Comment: This is incorrect.  "Adds x% to [Element] Damage" does not add to total damage.  It only adds to base weapon damage, and ignores other elemental damage sources. [Here are more details](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/elemental-damage-how-does-it-work), including a link to an archived copy of the Blizzard post on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

+x% elemental damage (whether cold, poison, fire, etc. it is all the same) is calculated as an increase to your base, non-elemental weapon damage (sometimes called "black weapon damage").

This base damage is a combination of rings, orbs, mojos, amulets, etc. that add damage, and your weapon damage before any elemental damage on your weapon is added.

This means that a 1000 DPS weapon with "black" damage (non-elemental) will benefit far more from +x% cold damage affixes than a 1000 DPS weapon that has elemental damage (whether fire, cold, poison, holy, etc.).

[Here are more details](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/elemental-damage-how-does-it-work), including a link to an archived copy of the Blizzard post on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your spell as a Witch Doctor.  For example, zombie bears and plague of toads "deal X% damage as Poison".  So you do 100k damage with toads as poison, that 6% mod on the item would make the toads do 106k.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/75336/26994) seems to be the correct answer based on empirical testing.

Comment: If you have no source, is this just a guess, or have you tested this?  You could test it by, say, equipping a weapon that does at least `+40 poison damage`, and see if a `+2-3% poison damage` amulet increases your `damage` stat by `currentDamageStat * 0.025` *(which would mean it applies to your current overall damage)* or if it just increases it by `(currentPoisonDamage*0.025)*attackSpeed * (1 + critChance*critDamage)` *(which would mean it only applies to your current poison damage)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft No, I couldn't test it yet. I'll update my answer as soon as I got fitting items for testing.