# How is +X% dmg to elemental skills being calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a WIZ level 60 and I am trying to do a cold-based WIZ which gives a quite high CC. I’m playing now Inferno ACT 1 with MP 1.

For gear, I have a couple of legendaries that give me +X% cold dmg and +X% dmg to cold skills, such as Fragment of Destiny (I know, only a lvl 59 weapon, 848dps and +29% dmg to cold skills) and frostburn gauntlets. I’m saving for triumvirate.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74409/does-percent-damage-type-increase-a-percentage-of-your-weapon-damage-or-only-d) addresses the +x% cold dmg  affix, but doesn't address the "+x% dmg to cold skills" affix, which is worded differently.

So the question is: How is +X% dmg to cold skills (or skills of other elemental types) being calculated?

Comment: I have nominated to reopen, as this question originally asked about two different affixes, and the question this was closed as a duplicate of only addresses one of the two.  I have edited the question to remove the duplicated part of the question, and focus instead on the one that is not answered by the other question.

Comment: @Beofett Is a separate question really needed?  Couldn't a complete answer on the duped question answer this as well?

Comment: @fbueckert Possibly, if we could migrate Wis' answer to the other one (I could edit his info into mine, but I don't want credit for his work). But I'm not convinced that that would be an ideal solution. Lumping two questions together, rather than addressing them separately, seems counter to our general format. It's akin to saying "shouldn't life steal mechanics be lumped in with life on hit mechanics?", even though both behave very differently.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74409/does-percent-damage-type-increase-a-percentage-of-your-weapon-damage-or-only-d

Comment: I edited my post to remove the small part stating that Beofett already did answer about the %elem damaga affix, as it does not have any sense after the changes made on the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm playing a Witch Doctor with exclusively fire-based skills. I chose to use [The Burning Axe Of Sankis](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-burning-axe-of-sankis) due to the large fire skill bonus. I can say this bonus is absolutely incredible and is pure bonus. By "pure bonus", I mean that a 20% bonus is a net 20% damages on every fire-based skill (I suppose every skill that is clearly noted as "fire damage").

My tests were performed as follows. First, I bought two axes with same dps (736.5 for the legendary fire-based axe and 737.2 for a random rare axe). Both axes didn't had any other dps modifier, except a 5% elemental damage on the legendary. I went on a map and compared the maximal crit I could get with both weapons (5-6 minutes with each). The difference was approximately the 17% of the legendary axe I bought (well, in fact the difference was more like 21%, I suppose this is due to the 5% elemental damage of the legendary).

Just a note : the fire-skill damage bonus is of course not reflected in my menu dps. It's some sort of "shadow dps".

Based on this, if you want to compare two weapons, one having an elemental-skill damage bonus, you should simply add this bonus to the dps of your char in menu when equipped with the weapon having the elemental-skill damage bonus (or dps computed on a web calculator if you are comparing some weapon in AH). This statement assume of course all of your skills are based on this element. It is almost true for my WD, it is certainly not true for a cold-sorcerer taking meteor.

Comment: I think you're right with your "shadow" dps concept. I noticed that my "fragment of destiny" with +30% dmg to cold skills has a higher dmg output then the dps mentioned in the character info screen. I also noticed the killing goes faster then with a weapon which should(comparison on item info) give me  higher DPS.  And for the record.....Meteor runed with comet makes it a 312% COLD dmg attack. SO it's true for a cold wizard ;-) trust me with the wand(+30%) and frostburn gauntlets(+29%) and Cold Blooded(passive +20%dmg)it HURTS.

Comment: Haha, did not know a rune can change the Meteor behavior to make cold damage. Not very realistic, but... who cares. Be careful when you mention that `cold skills has a higher dmg output then the dps mentioned in the character info screen`. The dps mentioned in the character info screen is not at all a damage output. It is just a computation that indicates how high is your dps. This value do not count any skill multiplier. What you should really want to compare is how much damage does your character do at each hit (assuming you dont change the attack speed when switching equipment).

Comment: " Not very realistic" ==> Wikipedia: A comet is an icy small Solar System body .....That out of the way ;-) What i wanted to so: Stuff dies faster with my "fragment" then with another weapon with no modifiers but with highr dps(within certain limits).